# Result is empty after while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Why is this not possible? Is there some way I can make the resolut not to be empty?

```
$sqlAllInfo = "SELECT item1, item2 FROM example";
$resAllInfo = mysql_query($sqlAllInfo);

while($rowAllInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($resAllInfo)){

    echo $rowAllInfo['item1'];

}

$rowAllInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($resAllInfo);

echo $rowAllinfo['item2'];
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Re what Colin said: For instance, you've clearly said that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7773141/157247) answers your question there.

Answer (score 2):

No, the result will always be empty after your while loop, because the while loop extracts all value from the result resource..
the while loop continues looping while there is still information to extract, and will finish when it is empty or when an error occurs

if you ment to get the last entry
$rowAllInfo still contains the last entry ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are looping through the result set using `while` **until there are no more results left**. The `while` loop exits when `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false`, because there are no more results. Calling `mysql_fetch_assoc` again still means that there are no more results.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
while($rowAllInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($resAllInfo)){
```

assigns a new value to `rowAllInfo` and afterwards checks whether it is still "true"-ish (as "true" as PHP can be ;-) )

Now, after the last row is fetched, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` will return false, which is then assigned to $rowAllInfo. As $rowAllInfo is now "false", the loop will not execute anymore, but - look - it's too late! You Variable already has the value `false` assigned to it.

Even after that, you call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` once again. But, as you have already fetched all rows within your loop, no more rows are left, and once again `$rowAllInfo` is set to "false".

So, whatever you are trying to do - this is probably not your way. A common way to achieve what I understand you are trying to do is the following:

```
$allRows = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
    $allRows[] = $row;
}

// show the array we just created...
echo print_r( $arrRows, 1 );
```