# show at the end of an image animation the last image

Tags: ios, animation

First excuse me for a maybe noob questions!!
I'm totally new in objective C!

I would like to animate images and at the end of the animation should show up the last image of the animation "dymchart20.png".
How can i do this?

here is my code of the animation:

```
aniChartView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart01.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart02.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart03.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart04.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart05.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart06.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart07.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart08.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart09.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart10.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart11.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart12.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart13.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart14.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart15.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart16.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart17.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart18.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart19.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart20.png"],nil];

// all frames will execute in 3 seconds
aniChartView.animationDuration = 0.8;
// repeat the annimation forever
aniChartView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
// start animating
[aniChartView startAnimating];
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a NSTimer and declaring your aniChartView as attribute of your class like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *aniChartView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)beginAnimation {
    self.aniChartView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart01.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart02.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart03.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart04.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart05.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart06.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart07.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart08.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart09.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart10.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart11.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart12.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart13.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart14.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart15.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart16.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart17.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart18.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart19.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart20.png"],nil];

    // all frames will execute in 3 seconds
    self.aniChartView.animationDuration = 0.8;
    // repeat the annimation forever
    self.aniChartView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    // start animating
    [self.aniChartView startAnimating];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8 target:self selector:@selector(staticImage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

}

-(void)staticImage {

    [self.aniChartView stopAnimating];
    [self.aniChartView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dymchart20.png"]];

}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you so much SonGoku68!! I did it and it works like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

Animations do not change the state of the element that they animate. Which means that if your uiview has a background image,  this image will be the same once the animation stops. 
The same thing goes for color changing with animation, or with any other property you animate.
To achieve your your goal, you have to explicitly invoke the change of UIImage to the one you want to see, once the animation ends. :)

Here is a solution that you might find useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/7773141/1306884